# Why Eclipse assigns project name like Main activity name while importing from existing code?

Tags: eclipse

I can create project with some name but if I should import this one to eclipse package explorer the project receives name like activity, e.g. SplashActivity. how to make that original name is not lost while importing?

Answer (score 0):

In order to rename an Eclipse project, right click the project -> Refactor -> Rename...

I got this from http://iappmania.blogspot.com/2013/01/rename-project-after-existing-android.html#.UQwftOgU9Ew